# Can't change root route rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a simple Todo list application in rails and I have the next problem:

I have a task that `belongs_to` project
I've created a template - `projects/show.html.erb`
And I can't set it to be the `root page` of my app, as I can see from the debugger - root is always `projects#index` action

P.S. I need show to be the root page cause I can't use this form in index action

```
 <%= form_for [@project, @task],remote: true do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :body,class: 'form-control' %>
          <%= f.submit 'Add task', class: 'btn' %>
        <% end %>
```

**projects controller**

```
 class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
     before_action :load_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
     before_action :authenticate_user!

     def index
        @projects = current_user.projects unless current_user.nil?
      end

      def show
        @task = @project.tasks.new
      end

      def new
        @project = current_user.projects.new
      end

      def edit
      end

      def create
        @project = current_user.projects.create(project_params)

        if @project.save
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          render :new
        end
      end

      def update
        if @project.update(project_params)
          redirect_to @project
        else
          render :edit
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @project.destroy
        redirect_to projects_path
      end

      private

    def load_project
      begin
        @project = Project.find(params[:id]) #raises an exception if project not found
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        redirect_to projects_path
      end
    end

      def project_params
        params.require(:project).permit(:name, :user_id)
      end

end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'projects#index'


  resources :projects do
    resources :tasks
  end




end
```

And routes generated by **rake routes**

```
todo$ rake routes
                          Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                    Controller#Action
                new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#new
                    user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#create
            destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                      devise/sessions#destroy
user_facebook_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/facebook(.:format)                 callbacks#passthru
 user_facebook_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/facebook/callback(.:format)        callbacks#facebook
                   user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#create
               new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)                  devise/passwords#new
              edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)                 devise/passwords#edit
                                 PATCH    /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
                                 PUT      /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
        cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                        devise/registrations#cancel
               user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#create
           new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                       devise/registrations#new
          edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                          devise/registrations#edit
                                 PATCH    /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                                 PUT      /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                                 DELETE   /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#destroy
                            root GET      /                                              home#index
                   project_tasks GET      /projects/:project_id/tasks(.:format)          tasks#index
                                 POST     /projects/:project_id/tasks(.:format)          tasks#create
                new_project_task GET      /projects/:project_id/tasks/new(.:format)      tasks#new
               edit_project_task GET      /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format) tasks#edit
                    project_task GET      /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#show
                                 PATCH    /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
                                 PUT      /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
                                 DELETE   /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#destroy
                        projects GET      /projects(.:format)                            projects#index
                                 POST     /projects(.:format)                            projects#create
                     new_project GET      /projects/new(.:format)                        projects#new
                    edit_project GET      /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                   projects#edit
                         project GET      /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#show
                                 PATCH    /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#update
                                 PUT      /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#update
                                 DELETE   /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#destroy
```

Comment: Why do you have to change the root dir? Do you mean you want to change the root _route_? Rails isn't a static server. The root dir doesn't effect which files are rendered. Anyway, if you want the projects show template to show on `/`, use this route:   `root 'projects#show'` however your show method requires a `project_id` param which wouldn't automatically be provided.

Comment: well there was a typo in my rutes.rb - i've fixed it.but `/` still redirects me to projects#index where I get an error with this form (cause I can't use form with such params in index action.as far as I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want the index to be show page? Well, how can you do that? The `show` action requires a `id` to be passed to the controller so that a particular project can be displayed to the user. How can you pass in a `id` when the user is requesting for `/`?

Does that make sense?

I would suggest you to leave the root to the `index` page. In the index view, link each project to its show page. Its unnecessary to have a nested form in the index page.

Or if you want to list all projects and tasks in the root page, modify your `index` view to loop through each project's tasks.

```
@projects.each do |project|
  # display project's information
  project.tasks.each do |task|
    # display the task information
    # display a new task button
  end
end
```

But you can't display the nested form like you asked. Because the form requires `@project` and `@task` which you can't determine in the `index action`. Maybe you can add `remote: true` to the "New task" and then trigger a JS response to render the form in a modal.

If this sounds new to you, please see https://launchschool.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails

This will walk through you using AJAX in your rails application.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The app must look like a page with project and its tasks ,so I can't create links to other pages

Comment: You want to display all the projects and their tasks in the root page?

Comment: Yes,after user sign in - he should take a look at all projects with all their tasks and be able to add tasks to a project via form

Comment: You don't understand my answer. Currently your `show` action requires a `@project` but if you make it root, then you will get an error, `No route matches missing required keys: [:id]`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: So what should I do to have a page looking like - http://prnt.sc/c3qawe ? Create some home page that will have button that redirects user to `show` page?

Comment: Thats the better way to do it. The screenshot you showed will require a lot of JS responses rather than HTML responses. I would suggest you to follow the tutorial I suggested. It'll help you.

Comment: well cause modal window is not an option for the app - I've created a homepage with one button `<%= link_to 'projects', 'projects#show', class: 'btn' %>` .But it redirects me to projects#index action (((
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120555/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-mikhah).